# MySQL: How can I display all attachments for an individual?

Tags: mysql, select

So, as an example, say I want to show all the projects attached to staff members. So I would use the following statement

```
SELECT Name, ProjectName
FROM Staff, Projects
ORDER BY Name
```

It would return something like this

```
Name | ProjectName

Adam | Project 1
Adam | Project 2
Bob  | Project 3
Bob  | Project 4
```

However, I want the results to be displayed like so

```
Name | ProjectName

Adam | Project 1
     | Project 2
Bob  | Project 3
     | Project 4
```

If this is possible, how can I alter my query to achieve this?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Make that change in the GUI.  Although it can be done in the database, such data formatting is more appropriate at the user-interface level.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have 3 ways to resolve your issue:

- if do you have a specific number of projects then you can do something like this:

  `SELECT Name, p1.ProjectName, p2.ProjectName, p3.ProjectName, p4.ProjectName FROM  Staff AS s  LEFT JOIN Projects AS p1 ON s.ProjectID = p1.ProjectID AND p1.ProjectID = 1  LEFT JOIN Projects AS p2 ON s.ProjectID = p2.ProjectID AND p2.ProjectID = 2  LEFT JOIN Projects AS p3 ON s.ProjectID = p3.ProjectID AND p3.ProjectID = 3  LEFT JOIN Projects AS p4 ON s.ProjectID = p4.ProjectID AND p4.ProjectID = 4 ORDER BY Name`
- using stored procedures.
- using loops outside the query.
  ex. in php:

  `while ($row = $res->fetch_row()) {
      $result[$row['Name']][] = $row['ProjectName'];
   }`